# Trying to return or list all excel files that have a specific worksheet name from nested directories

Tags: excel, vba, file

I want to list all files that have "x" as a worksheet name. So far I can list each excel file in a directory. I'm now trying to check these files for the existence of this worksheet name. The end goal would be to list which files have this worksheet and which ones don't in an existing excel file.

In the code below I get a 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range'. This occurs on

```vb
Workbooks("*.xls").Activate
```

```vb
            exists = False
            If Right(fileName, 4) = "xlsm" Or Right(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Then
                Workbooks("*.xls").Activate
                For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                    If Worksheets(i).Name = "RUNREADY" Then
                        MsgBox "Works"
                        exists = True
                    End If
                Next i
                If exists = True Then
                    Dim rr As String
                    rr = Workbooks("*.xls?").Worksheets("RUNREADY")
                    MsgBox rr
                End If

                'MsgBox folderPath & fileName
            End If
```

Comment: You can't use wildcards in a `Workbook` name reference. If you're previously opening the workbook, perhaps use a `Workbook` variable. `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open...`. That said, normally you don't need to `Activate`.

Comment: I was only using 'Activate' because I thought I was just looking at the filenames. I thought I wouldn't be able to check the worksheets unless it was Open in some way.

Comment: You can avoid using `Activate`. If you have a workbook variable `wb`, then you can fully qualify all `Worksheets` calls. For example, `For i = 1 to wb.Worksheets.Count`, or `If wb.Worksheets(i).Name`.

Comment: deleted that line and now I'm at the point where the `If Worksheet(i).Name = "RUNREADY"` isn't satisfied.

Comment: To loop through the worksheets i'd recommend you to declare a worksheet variable @R.Bourne, `Dim ws As Worksheet` and then, `For Each ws in  wb.Worksheets` `If ws.Name = "RUNREADY" then...` (wb is the workbook variable which BigBen told you about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a recursive function to search all subfolders from a given starting folder.  Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim rClear As Range
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim aSheetNames As Variant
    Dim ixResult As Long
    Dim msoMacroSetting As MsoAutomationSecurity

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set rDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") 'Change this to the correct sheetname and cell where results should be output to
    sFolderPath = "C:\Test"     'Change this to the correct folder path where you want to start your search
    aSheetNames = Array("RUNREADY", "Run Ready")    'Change this to the list correct sheet names you are searching for, note that it ignores case

    ReDim aResults(1 To 65000, 1 To 1)  'Assumes a maximum number of identified results of 65000
    ixResult = 0

    'Prevent workbook open code, prevent screen flickering, prevent calculations
    'This will let the code run smoother and faster without interruptions
    With Application
        msoMacroSetting = .AutomationSecurity
        .AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Call the recursive function ExcelFileSheetSearch
    ExcelFileSheetSearch sFolderPath, aSheetNames, aResults, ixResult

    'Re-enable what was disabled
    With Application
        .AutomationSecurity = msoMacroSetting
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    'Check if any workbooks were positively identified
    If ixResult > 0 Then
        'Clear previous results, preserving headers (if any)
        Set rClear = rDest.CurrentRegion
        rClear.Offset(rDest.Row - rClear.Row).ClearContents

        'Output results
        rDest.Resize(ixResult, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults
    Else
        MsgBox "No workbooks found in [" & sFolderPath & "] or any of its subfolders containing worksheets named: " & Chr(10) & Join(aSheetNames, Chr(10))
    End If

End Sub

Public Function ExcelFileSheetSearch(ByVal arg_sFolder As String, ByVal arg_vFindSheet As Variant, ByRef arg_aList As Variant, ByRef arg_ixList As Long) As Variant
'This is a recursive function that checks a given folder and all of its subfolders for Excel workbooks
'If any of the workbooks contain a worksheet with a specific name, it will add the folder path and file name to the results list

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim aSheets As Variant
    Dim vSheet As Variant
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim oSubFolder As Object
    Dim bSheetFound As Boolean

    'Ensure correct folder path structure
    If Right(arg_sFolder, Len(Application.PathSeparator)) <> Application.PathSeparator Then sFolder = arg_sFolder & Application.PathSeparator Else sFolder = arg_sFolder
    If Len(Dir(sFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Function    'Invalid folder path provided

    If IsArray(arg_vFindSheet) Then
        aSheets = arg_vFindSheet
    Else
        ReDim aSheets(1 To 1)
        aSheets(1) = arg_vFindSheet
    End If

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder(sFolder)

    'Loop through the given folder path looking for Excel files
    'Open found Excel files and check if the given sheet name exists
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        bSheetFound = False
        If (LCase(Right(oFile.Name, InStrRev(oFile.Name, "."))) Like LCase("*.xls*")) Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & oFile.Name)

            'Loop through each sheet name that is being searched for
            For Each vSheet In aSheets
                If SheetExists(CStr(vSheet), wb) Then
                    bSheetFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next vSheet
            If bSheetFound Then
                arg_ixList = arg_ixList + 1
                arg_aList(arg_ixList, 1) = sFolder & oFile.Name
            End If
            wb.Close False
        End If
    Next oFile

    'Function calls itself for each subfolder to run the check again
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        ExcelFileSheetSearch sFolder & oSubFolder.Name, arg_vFindSheet, arg_aList, arg_ixList
    Next oSubFolder

End Function

Public Function SheetExists(ByRef arg_sSheetName As String, Optional ByRef arg_wb As Workbook) As Boolean
'This function checks if a specific sheet name exists within a workbook

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If arg_wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook Else Set wb = arg_wb

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(arg_sSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    SheetExists = (Not (ws Is Nothing))

End Function
```

Comment: What would you change to look for multiple sheet names i.e variables including spaces, or difference in case. I ask this because users input this sheet name differently as in  "RUNREADY", "RUN READY", "RunReady".

Comment: @R.Bourne The sheet name search already ignores case, so it would match "RUNREADY" as well as "RunReady".  Changing the logic to search for more than one sheet name will be a bit more work, I'll get it updated shortly.

Comment: @R.Bourne See updated answer.  It now accepts an array for the sheet names to search for so you can list multiple possibilities.